# Tensor product of sheaf with vector space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to know what is the meaning of $V$$\otimes$$\mathcal{O}_X$.where $V$ is a vector space and $\mathcal{O}_X$ is structure sheaf of scheme $X$.What is the meaning of this tensor?Is $V$ consider as constant sheaf?

Comment: Where did you come across it?

Comment: You can either consider $V$ as a constant sheaf, or you can fix a basis $(e_i)$ and define $V\otimes \mathcal{O}_X=\bigoplus \mathcal{O}_X.e_i$. This does not depend on the chosen basis.

Comment: Concretely, you can think of this as the (globally free) sheaf of sections of the trivial vector bundle $V \times X \to X$.

Answer (score 2):

Abstractly, suppose $C$ is any $k$-linear category, meaning that it is [enriched](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) over $k$-vector spaces (its homsets are $k$-vector spaces and composition is bilinear). If $V$ is a $k$-vector space and $c \in C$ is an element of $C$, then the [tensoring](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower) or copowering $V \otimes c$, if it exists, is the object satisfying

$$[V \otimes c, d] \cong [V, [c, d]]$$

where $[-, -]$ means taking the hom vector space in $C$ on the LHS and means taking the hom vector space in either $C$ or $\text{Vect}$ on the RHS.

Concretely, if $C$ has arbitrary direct sums, it can be computed as

$$\bigoplus_i v_i \otimes c$$

where $v_i$ is a basis of $V$ and $v_i \otimes c$ is just notation for the copy of $c$ indexed by $i$. This is because the tensoring functor respects colimits in both variables.